# How do I know it has printed successfully or not using ReactToPrint

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
  content: () => componentRef.current,
  onBeforeGetContent: handleOnBeforeGetContent,
  // onAfterPrint: () => window.location.reload(),
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by *printed successfully*?

Comment: useReactToPrint doesn't print. It knows nothing _about_ printing, let alone printers. It only knows how to send a fake ctrl/cmd-p command so that the browser pops up the print dialog, with a bit of "React hook" veneer so you don't have to write that code yourself (even though the dependency is so huge that you're almost always better off just writing those few lines of code yourself).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.